# Create symmetric figures when using matplotlib labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization

I am using `plt.subplots` with both `ax.set_ylabel` and `fig.supylabel`. However, this creates figures that are off-centered.

Is it possible to automatically increase the right margin such that the red line is at the center of the figure?
[image]
In the case I am doing this manually, how can I precisely measure by how much I should increase the right margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
x = np.arange(50)
ax1.plot(x,np.sin(x))
ax2.plot(x,np.sin(x))
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2.set_yticklabels('')
ax1.set_title('damped')
ax2.set_title('undamped')
ax1.set_ylabel('amplitude')
fig.suptitle('Different types of oscillations')
```

Output:

[image]

---edit---

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as grd

fig = plt.subplots()

gs = grd.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=0.5)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])

x = np.arange(50)
ax1.plot(x,np.sin(x))
ax2.plot(x,np.sin(x))

ax1.set_title('damped')
ax2.set_title('undamped')
ax1.set_ylabel('amplitude')
```

The keypoint is `gs = grd.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=0.5)`. Adjust `wspace` as you like. The plot below is for `wspace=0.5`

[image]

Comment: Which version of Matplotlib are you using? On my machine, your code gives me the same problem of the graph in the question.

Comment: 3.2.1. Could it be that you are using ``constrained_layout=True`` in case if you just copy the code from https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-figure-title-py ? Remove ``constrained_layout=True`` or set it to ``False``

Comment: No, I am not using `constrained_layout=True`. I also tried to set `plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = False` but it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: post your code. I'll take a look. Maybe I'll see something you don't

Comment: I have just copy-pasted the code in your answer. And I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/6FpKfh5) result

Comment: Give another try with the code under ---edit---

Comment: This resolves the issue, thank you. Just I want to note that in more complex settings using the gridspec created an issue of too large margins. I have resolved it through `fig.subplots_adjust()`.